# How to hash a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, hash

I have a matrix like this:

```py
matrix = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
])
```

Is there any way for me to hash this matrix, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `hash`. what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to save this hash value into a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn it to bytes and than use `hashlib.sha1`

for example:

```
import hashlib
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(size=(3,3))
hash = hashlib.sha1(a.tobytes()).hexdigest()
print(hash)  # --> e12b2fe9d64df2661920eb81afb4d3bbd416e0bb

# one more time -> different hash code
a = np.random.random(size=(3,3))
hash = hashlib.sha1(a.tobytes()).hexdigest()
print(hash)  # --> 82912730024fe5d45ca996cfa6b2c8e00626d504
```